# Merge Sorting 3 Sorted Arrays

Tags: sorting, merge

Say I have 3 sorted arrays A1, A2, A3. I want to merge them using merge aspect in merge sort. How would I find that runtime?
I can't even suggest a solution, I'm completely stuck...
Thanks!

Comment: You can just use merge sort but with 3 blocks, using 2 comparisons per iteration. O(size(A1)+size(A2)+size(A3))

Comment: Yeah - like @Nick says, you just need to find the largest/smallest of the three values currently being indexed/iterated.

Comment: the size of the arrays are equal, what would a worst case runtime be?

Comment: O(size(A1)+size(A2)+size(A3)), 2 comparisons per element, remember that they are already sorted.

Comment: so if they are all size n it would be O of 3n?

Comment: Yeah, which is actually O(n)